# LINQ to SQL - The database generated a key that is already in use

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a simple problem that reads an Excel file (using interop) and fills an MSSQL database file with some data extracted from it. That's fine so far.
I have a Shops table with the following fields:

- ID: int, auto-generated, auto-sync: on insert
- Name: string
- Settlement: string
- County: string
- Address: string

I read the excel file, and then create a new Shops object and set the Name, Settlement, County and Address properties and I call Shops.InsertOnSubmit() with the new Shops object.

After this I have to reset the database (at least, the table), for which the easiest way I found was to call the DeleteDatabase() method and then call CreateDatabase() again.
The problem is, that after the first reset, when I try to fill the table again, I get the exception: The database generated a key that is already in use.

Additionally, from that point on, I'm unable to use that database file, because DatabaseExists() returns FALSE, but when I call the CreateDatabase() method, it throws an exception, that the database already exists (although the data files don't exist).

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are re-using the data-context beyond what is wise. Try disposing and re-creating the data-context after deleting the database.

I suspect the problem is that the identity manager is still tracking objects (destroying and recreating the database is such an edge-case that I think we can forgive it for not resetting itself here).

Comment: Thank you very much, I disposed the data context after deleting the database and then reinstantiated and recreated it, so it is working now. Thank you so very much!
One more thing: how can I 'release' the databases I created so far? MSSQL won't allow me to create databases with that name...

Comment: Thanks. I had similar problem because I left ASP.Net Development Server running while re-deploying database. I must remember to shutdown the Development Server before redeploying.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error. I had a log table, with an identity. I was truncating the log, while my application was running. What happened was the DB would start the identity column over again when I truncated, however the data context I was using to log still had objects it was tracking with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error because I was using a custom stored procedure for the insert with a table that had an identity column, but I had forgotten to "SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY" at the end of my sproc.

I wasn't actually using the resulting identity value so the problem only showed up when I inserted two or more rows.  Tricky bug.

Comment: I seem to encounter the same error, do you set @Id as output parameter of the sp?

Comment: I was probably using @Id as an output parameter.  Sorry I can't recall for sure, that was a long time ago and my memory isn't so strong :).